# CSS @import not working on Shopify

Tags: css, import, shopify, liquid

Currently building a Shopify theme and I'm using Gridset for the grid layout. My issue is, for IE 8/9 its required to use some CSS @import's however they don't seem to be working as the grid is breaking on only those versions.

For a standard site, you'd simple do the following

```
@import url("gridset-ie-a-spans1.css") only screen and (min-width:1025px);
```

I've tried adapting for Shopify by doing the following but not working:

```
@import url("{{ 'gridset-ie-a-spans1.css' | asset_url }}") only screen and (min-width:1025px);
```

and also

```
@import url("{{ 'gridset-ie-a-spans1.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}") only screen and (min-width:1025px);
```

Neither worked!

Does anybody know how to successfully get @imports to work, or proven alternatives?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[**Media queries**](http://www.brianhadaway.com/responsive-web-design-using-css3-media-queries/) are not supported at all in IE8 and below.

For IE9, you should be able to do this in your HTML:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gridset-ie-a-spans1.css" media="screen and (min-width:1025px)" />`

To add support for IE8, you could use one of several JS solutions. For example, [**this library**](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) can be added to add media query support for IE8 only with the following code :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script 
   src="css3-mediaqueries.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

[**Respond**](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) is another library that does the same thing. The code for adding that library to your HTML would be identical :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script 
   src="respond.min.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

If you don't like a JS based solution, you should also consider adding an IE<9 only stylesheet where you adjust your styling specific to IE<9. For that, you should add the following HTML to your code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style-ielt9.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Gridset uses these CSS import's to get around the lack of media queries support on IE8. My problem is that the CSS import's aren't working with Shopify. This would normally work on a standard website however I'm not sure how to get it working with Shopify. Thank you for your detailed response though

Comment: @user2498890 : AFAIK, media queries don't work in IE8 at all, including on import statements. This specific use of media queries is poorly documented, though, and I haven't tried it myself. Is it possible gridset uses JS under the hood to get media queries to work on import statements? Also, is it possible to provide an online demo of what you're trying to achieve? That makes it easier to figure out exactly what goes wrong in your specific use case.

Comment: All I know is that Gridset has a solution for making the grids work on IE8, it would be working in my case however something Shopify/Liquid related is causing the grids not to work. I'm presuming either I'm writing the Liquid tag wrong or you aren't able to use CSS import's on css.liquid files?

Comment: @user2498890 : My guess is that Shopify uses Javascript to get this code to work IE8 and that some fatal error somewhere in your Javascript code is preventing this behavior from being executed. Have you checked in your console whether you're getting any JS errors?